# How to change the position of the currency symbol relative to a number?

Tags: c#, string, char

Is it possible to change the place of '$' char in a string according to its relative position to a number?

Example:

```
string input = "the price is 18$. It increased to 24.50$ ."

output = "the price is $18. It increased to $24.50 ."
```

Comment: Yes... That answers the question but Im guessing u have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Regex for this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// ...

string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\$", "$$$1");
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BKvyTm/1)** | **[C# demo](https://rextester.com/AEU24225)**

#### Regex pattern details:

- `\b` - Word boundary to make sure it's a standalone number.
- `(` - Start of capturing group #1.

  - `\d+` - One or more digits.
  - `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group.

    - `\.\d+` - A dot followed by one or more digits.
  - `)` - Close the non-capturing group.
  - `?` - Make the previous group optional.
- `)` - Close group #1.
- `\$` - Match a dollar sign.

#### Replacement details:

- `$$` - Dollar sign.
- `$1` - Whatever was matched in group #1 (i.e., the number).

#### References:

- [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)